# How do I get medias posted by friends I followed on Instagram?

Tags: api, react-native, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to use Instagram API to retrieve all the recent pictures and videos my friends posted on their Instagram. I looked through all the endpoints in the Instagram document but I could not find any endpoints that let me do this. Am I missing something or does Instagram not have that endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported now. But if you already have an oauth app which is authorised to use `public_content` scope then you can use this API: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent to get the media from the user id.

Please note, Instagram has deprecated the `public_content` scope and no more issuing for new applications. Also, the Instagram API is scheduled to be deprecated by 2020 in favour of new FB graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user (which also doesn't have endpoint for fetching media which is not owned)